# Does Unix.mkdir set umask correctly?

Tags: unix, ocaml, mkdir, umask

I called `Unix.mkdir "test" 0o000` and expected directory with **`rwxrwxrwx`** permissions but had **`-------w-`**.
After call `Unix.mkdir "test" (Unix.umask 0o000)` I have the same result.

I can't understand why.

How to create directory with **`rwx`** permissions for all with OCaml `Unix` module?

Comment: The return value of `Unix.umask` is the old value of the `umask`. Furthermore it doesn't make a lot of sense to pass a `umask` value as your desired permisions. A `umask` value and a permissions value are, in some sense, specified using opposite meanings for their bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value you specify to `Unix.mkdir` is the permissions you want the directory to have, as modified by your current `umask`. If you specify `0o000` you should expect to create a directory with no permissions allowed to anybody. Since the `umask` can only *deny* some extra permissions, your reported result is impossible, at least in Unix.

Note that the second parameter to `Unix.mkdir` is not a umask value, it's a permissions value. The reason the OCaml documentation says to look at `umask` is so that you realize the specified value will be modified by your `umask`. It works like this: the directory will be created with the permissions you specify, except that any bit that is *set* in your `umask` will be *clear* in the resulting permissions. In other words, the `umask` specifies the accesses you wish to be denied by default.

If you really want to create a directory with all permissions allowed to everybody, you'll need to make sure your `umask` is 0. Here's what happens with a reasonable `umask` value of `0o022`:

```
$ umask
0022
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# #load "unix.cma";;
# Unix.mkdir "testing1" 0o777;;
- : unit = ()
# ^D
$ ls -ld testing1
drwxr-xr-x  2 jeffsco  staff  68 Jul 30 13:43 testing1
```

The resulting directory has all permissions allowed, except the 0o022 permissions of the umask. (No write permission for group or other.)

Here's what happens if you set your `umask` to 0 before creating the directory:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# #load "unix.cma";;
# Unix.umask 0o000;;
- : int = 18
# Unix.mkdir "testing2" 0o777;;
- : unit = ()
# ^D
$ ls -ld testing2
drwxrwxrwx  2 jeffsco  staff  68 Jul 30 13:45 testing2
```

When the `umask` is set to 0, the permissions of the created directory will be exactly those specified in the call to `Unix.mkdir`.